# getting error 400 on signing with google

Tags: google-signin

I want to create google login in my website and code used is from google developer website [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) and I am using php for coding and my code is

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Google Login</title>
 <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="9252517****-o9350mh2vrp58maddlv0aeitkd0c****.apps.googleusercontent.com">
 <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
 <script>
  function onSignIn(googleUser) 
  {
   var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
   console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
   console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
   console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
   console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
  }
  function signOut() 
  {
      var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
      auth2.signOut().then(function () 
      {
       console.log('User signed out.');
      });
    }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div align="center" margin-top="100px">
  <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
  <a href="#" onclick="signOut();">Sign out</a>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

After signin I am getting error like this Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
The JavaScript origin in the request: http://localhost did not match a registered JavaScript origin.
You can check error [here](https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?redirect_uri=storagerelay%3A%2F%2Fhttp%2Flocalhost%3Fid%3Dauth132433&response_type=permission&scope=email%20profile%20openid&openid.realm=&client_id=92525173937-o9350mh2vrp58maddlv0aeitkd0cdqe7.apps.googleusercontent.com&ss_domain=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&fetch_basic_profile=true).

Please help me to get out of this problem.

Comment: I don't think you can use google signin on localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long search I found solution which magically solve my problem.
As shown in error *http://localhost did not match a registered JavaScript origin* I set http://localhost instead of full path in my redirect url in console.developer site and it works.